# esc/pos command how to calculate the nL nH?

Tags: javascript, php, c

I want to set the position of the head of the printer through the ESC / pos:

```
ESC $ Set the absolute horizontal position
ESC $ nL nH
```

How do I calculate the `nL`, `nH`?

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you tried so far? What exactly is not working as expected? Currently your question is not clear enough for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is excerpt from documentation for some printer like yours:
"NAME: Set absolute print position
FUNCTION: Sets the distance from the beginning of the line
RANGE: 0 ≤ nL ≤ 255 0 ≤ nH ≤ 255
[Details] ·The distance from the beginning of the line to the print position is
[(nL + nH x 256) x (horizontal motion unit)] inches.

nH - number of printing symbol positions from the begin of the line,
nL - number of printing points  from the begin of the line. And it seems that each symbol position conststs of 256 points.

So, nL is the remainder from disivion horizontal position by 256 and is used for "fine tuning" of horizontal position.

So, given head position offset from line begin (in inches) you get:

```
$nL = floor(($offsetFromLineBeginInInches/$horizontal_motion_unit) / 256);
$nH = ($offsetFromLineBeginInInches/$horizontal_motion_unit) % 256;
```

default horizontal motion unit you can look up in documentation for your specific printer

Comment: I do not know how to count nH - number of printing points from the begin of the line. What is the point?

Comment: Не совсем понятно horizontal motion unit они в чем меряются ? 1/120 inch так и подставлять в формулу дробное значение ?

Comment: yes, if for your printer's horizontal motion unit is 1/120 inch then $nH = ($offsetFromLineBeginInInches/(1/120.0)) % 256 and
$nL = intdiv($offsetFromLineBeginInInches/(1/120.0), 256). And $offsetFromLineBeginInInches value should be in inches

Comment: Тогда операция MOD теряет смысл, единицы в расчетах получаются не целые.

Comment: Нет, смысл не теряется - при округлении, получается 2 целочисленных смещения: nL -  в знакоместах, nH - в пикселях. Единственное - да, nL округлять надо всегда в меньшую сторону. Этот момент в ответе поправлю

Comment: Я в экселе забил формулу и смотрю =MOD(3,9*(1/120);256)=0,0325 не получается целое

Comment: 3,9 не умножить, а разделить надо: nH = (3.9/(1/120.0) % 256) = 212, nL = floor(3.9/(1/120.0) / 256) = 1;

Comment: Если судить по документации то надо умножать. В любом случае это не работает, принтер печатает совсем не там где ожидалось.